# Unable to do "WITH" statement: "SQL Error [57]: ... Schema must be specified when session schema is not set"

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a WITH statement in DBeaver built on Presto (I may have a gap in knowledge of the underlying tools and structure).

Simple query:

```
with t1 as (select run_id from john.link_budget limit 10)
select a.run_id
from a
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [57]: Query failed (#20230313_181242_00253_h9j4c): line 6:6: Schema must be specified when session schema is not set
```

What does `Schema must be specified when session schema is not set` mean and how could I fix it?

Comment: `from a` -> `from t1`.

Comment: Use `from t1` instead of `from a` and remove `a.`. Why your are using CTE for a simple select Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a typo.  Change `from a` to `from t1`, query runs successfully.